# JQuery & PHP requests. What's more efficient?

Tags: php, jquery

As I learn more and more about JQuery & PHP requests, a couple things have occured to me.

I've designed a web page with a bunch of empty DIVs that are populate by Ajax calls during and after this page loads. So far, in order for this page to load, I make a total of 8 (.get()) calls using JQuery/Ajax to php pages, get the results and populate this divs.

1. On initial web page load, is it wise to:

A. Make 8 Ajax calls to 8 different PHP pages or...
B. Make 1 Ajax call to 1 PHP page that generates the content of all previous 8 together?

1. I've decided to use Ajax so that once page loads, each future user action is made through an Ajax call and would not require all of these original calls to be made again which I think would save a lot of server resources, etc..

Can any of you give some pointers on light-weight and efficient developing guidelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to minimize your AJAX calls on page load. In a perfect world, the only AJAX calls being made would be due to user interaction AFTER the document has loaded. This means you should code your backend in a way that assembles and displays the entire page content initially.

On a side note, it's a good idea to make AJAX sites backwards compatible. Something in your PHP like:

```
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');

if(!IS_AJAX) { require_once("header.php"); }
echo "this is ajax content";
if(!IS_AJAX) { require_once("footerer.php"); }
```

This will detect whether or not it was an ajax request, and if not display the header and footer for normal operation.

Comment: So "0 AJAX requests on page load" is better than "1 AJAX request on page load" is better than "8 AJAX requests on page load". Right?

Comment: Correct! The same logic applies to style sheets, javascript files, etc. The more requests the less responsive your site will seem. There are always exceptions, and with AJAX atleast the rest of the site will render. An acceptible application might be a data-intensive site query that slows down your whole site--putting this in an ajax request will make the site seem faster while it loads.

Comment: don't rely on those headers, they cannot be guaranteed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393904/ajax-only-access/1393923#1393923

Comment: Alright. So basically, the idea is to generate the entire page with PHP on load and once loaded, all user actions are ideally made through isolated Ajax calls.