# Only allowing PHP files to run with 'authorization' from previous web page

Tags: php, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AJAX only access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393904/ajax-only-access)

So I have these javascript functions I run depending on who won a contest.

```
function winA() 
{
var x = "<?php echo $id;?>"
$.ajax({ url: 'win.php' ,
         data: { id: x }
   }); 
}

function winB() 
{
var val = "<?php echo $i;?>"
$.ajax({ url: 'win.php' ,
         data: { id: val }
   }); 
}
```

The file win.php updates a MySQL with who won. What troubles me is if someone simply goes to

http://mysite.com/win.php?id=1

and refreshes it a whole lot of times I clearly will have some incorrect results on the MySQL server.

I am wondering exactly how one would make it so that URL could only be accessed when appropriate, via this ajax call. Alternatively make it so the win.php file only to actually execute when it has 'authorization' that expires after loading the php file.

Thanks in advance, Aaron.

Comment: you should use a session to hold who won then ajax like your doing but with no params, then do your update then unset the session var. also `winA()` is basically the same as `winB()` why not just pass a value like `win(value)`

Comment: I am trying to get it to run win.php, and I do need to pass params in, how would I do it without?

Comment: This is different question but [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10470118/1338846) may be helpful, you can also add some checks with `$_SESSION` to see if game was properly started before writing to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a session, expanding from my comment:

**Main game page**

```
<?php
session_start();

//Do game....

//Decide Winner

$_SESSION['winner']='A'; //or B depending on who won

?>
```

**Then an AJAX request with blank params ect, just so won.php gets touched**

```
function win(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "win.php",
    cache: false
  }).done(function(html){
   //Dont do anything or you could get a response from the won.php request an update something
  });
 }
```

**Win.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['winner'])){
    $winner=$_SESSION['winner'];
    //Do update ect

    //Unset Winner session var, by unsetting the user would need to play the game again to get it set
    unset($_SESSION['winner']);
}else{
    header('Location: ./index.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: What exactly does $_SESSION affect?

Comment: With `$_SESSION` vars you can pass values from one page to another without passing a value in a HTTP request of sort eg _POST _GET, its basically a cookie set on the server that's valid while your browser is open

Comment: Also the game that I'm finding the winner of isn't done in php its done in javascript, so I'm having trouble imagining that $_SESSION would work properly if it needs to be set depending on which of my methods are called because PHP is server side and gets loaded on start

Comment: If the game is done in javascript then its 100% hackable, a player only needs to look at the source and construct a HTTP request to inject scores into the db. You need something server side to validate whats going on.

Comment: Yeah and that is why I'm trying to figure out how to use this $_SESSION thing to make it not possible

Comment: Am I able to use session to hold who won in the middle of a javascript function?

Comment: The core logic of the game eg who wins should be decided by PHP server side and rendered client side.

Comment: If you primary code is javascript then you will in no way make your code 100% secure from hackers.  There's just no way.  Hackers can and will easily destroy your DB

Comment: Imagine if this game is simply clicking one button or another, is there a way to pass which button was clicked using session?

Comment: Yes, in both PHP and JS but anything you do with the JS is vulnerable to attacks making any effort you put into it now to prevent users from refreshing the page multiple times, a waste of time.

Comment: As long as the winner is not in the js code thats viewable within the source then you can use ajax to pass which button was pressed, then PHP will decide if its the correct one. You should decide which is winner before any output is printed to page, else its hackable.

Comment: Would it be possible for a hacker to spoof false session information?

Comment: No, as its server side. all the user can see is the session id, which is a key to a file on the server the file is holding the variables, unless a hacker has access to the server and opens the file to directly edit it its impossible

Comment: Perfect, the solution I am using is to make 2 session variables for the two possible winners, then to use ajax to call win.php with a parameter indicating which session variable was indeed the winner.

Comment: Is there any way to check if the session variables were set properly?

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP, on the page which is suppose to take you to the `http://mysite.com/win.php?id=1` just use a hidden input with a value like

```
<input type="hidden" name="verify">
```

On the page `http://mysite.com/win.php?id=1` at the beginning put something like

```
if (isset($_POST['verify'])) {
   // perform what you want
} else {
   header("Location: wherever/you/want");
}
```

The page won't run unless that hidden `$_POST['verify']` has been set.

Perhaps if you are using unique names in your DB for your contests, you could also check for it's existence in a query prior to running the function to insert the new data as well.

To run a query check, lets assume that each contest name has a unique id or name.  We'll call contest A 'id 1' and assume it's the primary key in your table.  Run a query to check for that id like so:

```
function checkContest() {
  $connection = // your connection info;
  $query = "SELECT *
            FROM table
            WHERE id = '1'";

  $result = $connection -> query($query);

  if ($result -> num_rows > 0) {
     // end function
  } else {
     // call the function that contains the INSERT query
  }
```

Then in your ajax, you call the new function checkContest() (or the handler file it's in) instead of the function in win.php (because the new function calls the win.php function only upon success)

Comment: Whats to stop a multi_curl request iterated 1M times with varify as a post param

Comment: PHP.  Lawrence is right, it could still be susceptible to attacks by just using the `hidden` input.  But if you run a query check (PHP) prior to inserting the new data into your DB, then you should be good.  Again, assuming you are using unique names or identifiers in the DB for each contest

Comment: @JT Smith how would I pass the hidden input through ajax?

Comment: Running a query check method/function will be the better way Aaron.  You won't need to pass any additional parameters through ajax either

Comment: This of course is assuming you know _some_ php (assumed because you are calling/instantiating it with your ajax to inject values into a DB).  Or are you using someone else's code?

Comment: I do know php, I'm just new so I obviously haven't used it to the greatest extent of its ability, explain what you mean by "Running a query check method/function"

Comment: For future reference could you explain how to pass hidden parameters in ajax?

Comment: I updated my answer for you on the query check.  It's basic but should give you an idea of how to do it or at least where to start

Comment: I'm not too familiar with ajax, only used it a couple times thus far, but you would pass the hidden input field just like you would any other field, you would put it's parameters in your `data` set like you did with `id` in your current code.  You can pass more than 1 parameter via ajax call, if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the win.php file to run one time only for winA() and one time only for winB() you could add an extra property to the data object you're passing in your AJAX calls from each function which identifies which function it came from (ex: func: "A").

Then in win.php you'll need to keep track of whether or not winA or winB has been won.  That could be a session variable or you could just create a small table in your db which has 2 fields - "contest" and "won", and 2 rows (one for winA, one for winB).  The first time win.php is called by either function you update the "won" column and any subsequent calls you check that column first and if it's not null then you know the contest is already won and skip the rest of the win.php processing.

Generally when I want to add some sort of limitation like this I prefer to do it server side as it's somewhat easier to control and more difficult for others to manipulate.