# Is there a way to protect direct access to pages - but allow ajax requests?

Tags: php, jquery

I have some pages that return a JSON request that are used in jQuery via AJAX. What I need to do is somehow block direct access to the file. So only allow JSON (AJAX) requests but not direct access to the file.

So if I have the following jQuery code:

```
    $.getJSON("ajax/returnDate.php", {
        id: $(this).val()
        },function (data) {
        //more code
        }
    )
```

An unauthorized user can see this code. This will allow them to go to the following url and obtain the data they need.
domain.com/ajax/returnDate.php

So I need to write code to not allow direct access to returnDate.php but allow json request to be made.

How can I handle this?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: you can check at page load if the user is authorized. I believe you are either using session or cookies. So just check the session or cookie and decide wether to proceed or redirect user somewhere else.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1393923/973155

Comment: possible duplicate of [AJAX only access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393904/ajax-only-access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get Operations are never secure and are subject to "get replay attacks",CSRF, and XSS.
2. HTTP headers can be easily spoofed if your concern is unauthorized access.

I suggest the following:

1. changing to a "POST" operation from a "GET" operation
2. When you serve the page, place an antiforgery token into the URL for the AJAX POST operation
3. Check the antiforgery token on every ajax request POST operation
4. Generate a new Antiforgery token on every page.
5. Ask yourself : would Sabu code it that way?

Comment: What is an antiforgery token?

Comment: A Unique Token Generated every time your pages loads.  All the other techniques being suggested are very easy to circumvent if not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax requests should have an extra header `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` and the value would be `xmlhttprequest`, so you can add a check

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'xmlhttprequest'
```

Please note that this can still be imitated by an curl library, It's just an extra line of security

Comment: That can easily be spoofed

Answer (score 0):

When ever you use jQuery to make ajax calls it sets the a header `HTTP_X-Requested-With`. You can check for that and redirect the user if its false using the `header(Location: anything.php)` function

```
$isXhr = isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"])
         AND strotlower($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) == "xmlhttprequest";
```

please note to ensure proper security becaause this header can be injected manually in the header and access the page by some mallciuos user.